# Can't click Leaflet imageOverlay because of canvas which is above it

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

If I add an image to Leaflet map as an overlay with the code

```
let newOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(mapObj);
newOverlay.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let thisImg = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(thisImg);
});
```

I see my image on the map, but when I click it, the `<canvas>` element is clicked which is above the image with `z-index: 100` and extends to the full width and height of the screen. If I add `z-index: 200` to the image, it doesn't help.

Maybe it's more HTML/CSS issue than Leaflet and JS, but I'm not sure and can't resolve.

Comment: can you please create a demo: https://leafletjs.com/edit.html

Comment: @FalkeDesign you may add even their example by the link https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay and below add the event listener with simple alert() for example

Comment: https://plnkr.co/plunk/OuPcGELQFnOEOjnL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ImageOverlay `interactive`, then it is clickable:

```
var newOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {interactive: true}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to react to a click on any part of the overlying canvas you could set it to have `pointer-events: none`

Here's a trivial example where the top element does not react to a click:

```css
.under,
.over {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.under {
  background-color: pink;
}

.over {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="under" onclick="alert('under clicked');"></div>
<div class="over" onclick="alert('over clicked');"></div>
```